# Making massive amounts of individual row updates faster or more efficient

Tags: java, sql-server, multithreading, spring, transactions

I'm writing a java application that copies one database's information (db2) to anther database (sql server). The order of operations is very simple:

1. Check to see if anything has been updated in a certain time frame
2. Grab everything from the first database that is within the designated time frame
3. Map database information to POJOs
4. Divide subsets of POJOs into threads (pre defined # in properties file)
5. Threads cycle through each POJO Individually
6. Update the second database

I have everything working just fine, but at certain times of the day there is a huge jump in the amount of updates that need to take place (can get in to the hundreds of thousands).

Below you can see a generic version of my code. It follows the basic algorithm of the application. Object is generic, the actual application has 5 different types of specified objects each with its own updater thread class. But the generic functions below are exactly what they all look like. And in the `updateDatabase()` method, they all get added to `threads` and all run at the same time.

```
private void updateDatabase()
{
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    addObjectThreads( threads );     
    startThreads( threads );
    joinAllThreads( threads );
}

private void addObjectThreads( List<Thread> threads )
{
    List<Object> objects = getTransformService().getObjects();
    logger.info( "Found " + objects.size() + " Objects" );
    createThreads( threads, objects, ObjectUpdaterThread.class );
}

private void createThreads( List<Thread> threads, List<?> objects, Class threadClass )
{
    final int BASE_OBJECT_LOAD = 1;
    int objectLoad = objects.size() / Database.getMaxThreads() > 0 ? objects.size() / Database.getMaxThreads() + BASE_OBJECT_LOAD : BASE_OBJECT_LOAD;

    for (int i = 0; i < (objects.size() / objectLoad); ++i)
    {
        int startIndex = i * objectLoad;
        int endIndex = (i + 1) * objectLoad;
        try
        {
            List<?> objectSubList = objects.subList( startIndex, endIndex > objects.size() ? objects.size() : endIndex );
            threads.add( new Thread( (Thread) threadClass.getConstructor( List.class ).newInstance( objectSubList ) ) );
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.error( exception.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}


public class ObjectUpdaterThread extends BaseUpdaterThread
{
    private List<Object> objects;
    final private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( ObjectUpdaterThread.class );

    public ObjectUpdaterThread( List<Object> objects)
    {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for (Object object : objects)
        {
            logger.info( "Now Updating Object: " + object.getId() );
            getTransformService().updateObject( object );
        }
    }
}
```

All of these go to a spring service that looks like the code below. Again its generic, but each type of object has the exact same type of logic to them. The getObjects() from the code above are just one line pass throughs to the DAO so no need to really post that.

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class TransformServiceImpl implements TransformService
{
    final private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( TransformServiceImpl.class );

    @Autowired
    private TransformDao transformDao;

    @Override
    public void updateObject( Object object )
    {
        String sql;
        if ( object.exists() )
        {
            sql = Object.Mapper.UPDATE;
        }
        else
        {
            sql = Object.Mapper.INSERT;
        }

        boolean isCompleted = false;
        while ( !isCompleted )
        {
            try
            {
                transformDao.updateObject( object, sql );
                isCompleted = true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                logger.error( exception.getMessage() );
                threadSleep();
                logger.info( "Now retrying update for Object: " + object.getId() );
            }
        }
        logger.info( "Updated Object: " + object.getId() );
    }
}
```

Finally these all go to the DAO that looks like this:

```
@Repository
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class TransformDaoImpl implements TransformDao
{
    //@Resource is like @Autowired but with the added option of being able to specify the name
    //Good for autowiring two different instances of the same class [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate]
    //Another alternative = @Autowired @Qualifier(BEAN_NAME)
    @Resource(name = "db2")
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate db2;

    @Resource(name = "sqlServer")
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate sqlServer;

    final private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( TransformerImpl.class );

    @Override
    public void updateObject( Objet object, String sql )
    {
        MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        source.addValue( "column1_value", object.getColumn1Value() );
        //put all source values from the POJO in just like above

        sqlServer.update( sql, source );
    }
}
```

My insert statements look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO dbo.OBJECT_TABLE " +
"(COLUMN1, COLUMN2...) " +
"VALUES(:column1_value, :column2_value... "
```

And my update statements look like this:

```
"UPDATE dbo.OBJECT_TABLE SET " +
"COLUMN1 = :column1_value, COLUMN2 = :column2_value, " +
"WHERE PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN = :primary_key_value"
```

Its a lot of code and stuff I know, But I just wanted to layout everything I have in hopes that I can get help making this faster or more efficient. It takes hours on hours to update so many rows and it would nice if it only took a couple/few hours instead hours on hours. Thanks for any help. I welcome all learning experiences about spring, threads and databases.

Comment: If you're stuck with individual row updates it's always going to be inefficient. Are you sure you're not able to use set-based logic instead?

Comment: Most efficient is to make a dump of the tables (and import them on the target). If you need to make updates to individual columns of already existing rows, you are pretty much out of luck; if you're updating "just because", try delete and re-insert instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending large amounts of SQL to the server, you should consider Batching it using the `Statement.addBatch` and `Statement.executeBatch` methods. The batches are finite in size (I always limited mine to 64K of SQL), but they dramatically lower the round trips to the database.

As I was iterating and creating SQL, I would keep track of how much I had batched already, when the SQL crossed the 64K boundary, I'd fire off an `executeBatch` and start a fresh one.

You may want to experiment with the 64K number, it may have been an Oracle limitation, which I was using at the time.

I can't speak to Spring, but batching is a part of the JDBC `Statement`. I'm sure it's straightforward to get to this.

Comment: You got me on the right track for sure thanks. I used the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate's batchUpdate method and although still not as fast as I would like, it was definitely a little faster. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Check to see if anything has been updated in a certain time frame
> 2. Grab everything from the first database that is within the designated time frame

Is there an index on the LAST_UPDATED_DATE column (or whatever you're using) in the source table?  Rather than put the burden on your application, if it's within your control, why not write some triggers in the source database that create entries in an "update log" table?  That way, all that your app would need to do is consume and execute those entries.

How are you managing your transactions?  If you're creating a new transaction for each operation it's going to be brutally slow.

Regarding the threading code, have you considered using something more standard rather than writing your own?  What you have is a pretty typical [producer/consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) and Java has excellent support for that type of thing with [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and [numerous queue implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to move data between threads that perform different tasks.

The benefit with using something off the shelf is that 1) it's well tested 2) there are numerous tuning options and sizing strategies that you can adjust to increase performance.

Also, rather than use 5 different thread types for each type of object that needs to be processed, have you considered encapsulating the processing logic for each type into separate strategy classes?  That way, you could use a single pool of worker threads (which would be easier to size and tune).